# unconfigured columnfamily Cassandra Error while Using POJO

Tags: java, cassandra, cql

I am following the link below to insert an Person object into Person table resides on Cassandra servers
http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/1.0.4.RELEASE/reference/html/cassandra.core.html

But I am having `unconfigured columnfamily  error`. I have tested several ways to make it possible. Some ways are worked properly. here is the result.

**1- RUN PROPERLY**

```
    PreparedStatement statement = session.prepare("INSERT INTO \"tims\".\"Person\" (id, name, age) VALUES (?,?,?)");
int id=1234;
    String name="Ahmet"+id;
    int age=33;
BoundStatement bind = statement.bind(id,name,age);
    session.executeAsync(bind);
```

**2-  RUN PROPERLY**

```
String cql = "insert into \"tims\".\"Person\" (id, name, age) values (2345, 'Ali-updated-2', 39)";
        CassandraOperations cassandraOps = new CassandraTemplate(session);

        cassandraOps.execute(cql);
```

**3- DOES NOT RUN PROPERLY**

```
CassandraOperations cassandraOps = new CassandraTemplate(session);
cassandraOps.insert(new Person(2345, "Ahmet-updated", 33));
```

**Here is the POJO CLASS**

```
package com.ttech.tims.bipcamp.dao.cassandra;

import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.PrimaryKey;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.mapping.Table;

@Table(value="Person")
public class Person {


    @PrimaryKey(value="id")
    @Column(value="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(value="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(value="age")
    private int age;

    public Person(int id, String name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have downloaded the source code of the following API

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

What I have found is that following method returns value of first column of row
`cassandraOps.queryForObject(s, Person.class)` has the following method trace.

```
CqlTemplate-> processOne()

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@Override
public <T> T processOne(ResultSet resultSet, Class<T> requiredType) throws DataAccessException {
    if (resultSet == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Row row = resultSet.one();
    if (row == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return (T) firstColumnToObject(row);
}
```

I have used other two samples:

```
Map map = cassandraOps.queryForMap(s);

System.out.println("id:"+map.get("id")+", name:"+map.get("name")+", age:"+map.get("age"));

Person person = cassandraOps.queryForObject(s, new RowMapper<Person>(){

    @Override
    public Person mapRow(Row row, int rowNum) throws DriverException {
        return new Person(row.getInt(0), row.getString(1),row.getInt(2));
    }
});

System.out.println("Person:"+person);
```

I have found actual solution for the insert statement with keyspace. Updating dependency list with the followings.

```
<properties>
    <org.springframework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-cassandra</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```